# Showing a Save Toolbar Button in iOS using Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm sure this is a simple thing to do, but somehow I cannot find any good information about it. Using Xamarin Forms, I'm trying to add a simple Save toolbar button (in iOS) to the top right in the title bar.

What in the world am I missing? :D

Bonusproblem, all my icons are grey squares...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Page` has a `ToolBarItems` property which serves this purpose. You can add `ToolBarItem`s to it and they will be visible depending on the context (for iOS, they'll be visible if your `Page` is in a `NavigationPage`.

So this should do what you expect:

```cs
public static Page GetMainPage ()
{
    var label = new Label { Text = "content" };
    return new NavigationPage (new ContentPage {
        Title = "mypage",
        ToolbarItems = {
            new ToolbarItem {
                Name = "Save",
                Command = new Command (() => {
                    label.Text = "saved";
                }),
            }
        },
        Content = label,
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, this works great. My problem was that the page I was trying to set the ToolbarItems from was in a TabbedPage. My bad... :D